# Why is the regex quantifier {n,} more greedy than + (in Python)?

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I tried to use regexes for finding max-length sequences formed from repeated doubled letters, like `AABB` in the string `xAAABBBBy`.

As described in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> The `'*'`, `'+'`, and `'?'` quantifiers are all *greedy*; they match as much text as possible.

When I use the quantifier `{n,}`, I get a full substring, but `+` returns only parts:

```python
import re

print(re.findall("((AA|BB){3,})", "xAAABBBBy"))
# [('AABBBB', 'BB')]
print(re.findall("((AA|BB)+)", "xAAABBBBy"))
# [('AA', 'AA'), ('BBBB', 'BB')]
```

Why is `{n,}` more greedy than `+`?

Comment: because the leftmost match wins. The second pattern matches the two first "A", can't match the remaining A, and matches the Bs. The first pattern starts at the second A.

Comment: Besides `(AA|BB){3,}` is not really equivalent of `(AA|BB)+`. `(AA|BB){1,}` will behave same

Comment: Both patterns are greedy and matches as much as possible chars. But the second pattern can match 1 or more times but not 2 times. As the quantifier is 1 or more times, the pattern has a match. But the "rule" for the first pattern is 3 or more times, so the pattern can not match `BB` after the first `AA` in `AAABB` and moves to the second A and tries again and then it can match at least 3 times either `AA` or `BB`

Comment: @Anton Ganichev by the way, what was your expected output, the "max length sequence" in the string?

Answer (score 5):

Both quantifiers `{3,}` and `+` are greedy in the same way.

First, let's simplify the output a little bit by changing the inner group into a non-capturing one:

```
import re

print(re.findall("((?:AA|BB){3,})", "xAAABBBBy"))
# ['AABBBB']
print(re.findall("((?:AA|BB)+)", "xAAABBBBy"))
# ['AA', 'BBBB']
```

The first pattern requires a repetition (with the total number of occurrences being at least 3 – let's call this *multiplicity ≥3*), so the only possible match starts at the second `A`:

> `x` `A` ⟨**`A` `A` `B` `B` `B` `B`**⟩ `y`

The second pattern requires only multiplicity ≥1. As the string is scanned left-to-right, the first (left-most) possible greedy match is formed by the first two `A`s. For the remaining string `ABBBBy`, the first (left-most) possible greedy match is `BBBB`. After that, only `y` remains, which can't be matched.

> `x` ⟨**`A` `A`**⟩ `A` ⟨**`B` `B` `B` `B`**⟩ `y`